# Excel Minimum value dependent on grouped data

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, minimum, lookup-tables

```
Race Name   Location    Race Date   Odds    Minimum
Race 1      Jackson     2015-06-29  4.6 
Race 1      Jackson     2015-06-29  2.2     2.2
Race 1      Jackson     2015-06-29  26  
Race 1      Jackson     2015-06-29  9.5 
Race 2      Jackson     2015-06-29  8   
Race 2      Jackson     2015-06-29  2.8     2.8
Race 2      Jackson     2015-06-29  26  
Race 2      Jackson     2015-06-29  21  
Race 3      Jackson     2015-06-29  5.5 
Race 3      Jackson     2015-06-29  3.2     3.2
Race 3      Jackson     2015-06-29  17
```

The closest thing I could find on this was in this previous question. [Excel: find the minimum value in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655713/excel-find-the-minimum-value-in-range)

But I m struggling to implement this here.

I want to find the minimum Odds for each race, dependent on location, Race Date, and Race name.  As there are many 'Race 1' on '2015-06-29' with different locations. So I m guessing maybe a way of making an array that is dependent on the cells to group?

The desired output would have the minimum of each race written next to the corresponding row.

I m suspecting it may be something I need to make in VBA?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do what you are suggesting. What you want to do is form a unique key of Race, Number, Location, and Date. The quickest way to do this would be to insert a column in front then do this:

```
Key
=B2&C2&D2&E2
```

That will give you:

```
Race1Jackson42184   # This is just the date code. It increments by one for each day.
```

Now what you do is sort in `Ascending Order` on `Column A` and on the `Odds` column.

you can now enter this formula into the Minimum:

```
=IF(F3>F2,"",F3)
```

and that will give you the minimum for each race.

You could nest your if statement to make sure that one race didn't go off with all favorites and one with all long shots and test to make sure that the comparison is to the same race, but this works pretty efficiently without VBA or messy formulas that you will need to debug.

If you need to keep the order the same as the original, copy the data to a new sheet, perform the sort, then create a new key that that adds the odds column.

```
=B2&C2&D2&E2&F2
```

From there you can just do a vlookup from the original sheet to the new sheet, and as each row in the data table will now have a unique id then the vlookup will find the value of the If formula and you will get in with your original ordering.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is similar to the one in the link you provided. Just a couple more criterias. Adjust the ranges accordingly. You will need to enter this formula by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

```
=IF(MIN(IF($A$2:$A$20=A2,IF($B$2:$B$20=B2,IF($C$2:$C$20=C2,$D$2:$D$20))))=D2,MIN(IF($A$2:$A$20=A2,IF($B$2:$B$20=B2,IF($C$2:$C$20=C2,$D$2:$D$20)))),"")
```

Comment: I get what you are looking for now. See my updated formula. Column A is Race Name, Column B is Location, etc.

Comment: Glad to help! Can you close this question?

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You just need to create a PivotTable. Then add the RaceName field to the Row labels. And finally, you just need to add the Odds field to the Values. Then configure the Odds value clicking in the black little arrow and selecting "Value field settings" then choosing "Min" in the "Summarize value field by" tab.